# Google Maps advanced zoom levels

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am building a website that includes a map. However at zoom level 7 it is too small and at level 8 it is too big.

Is there a way to zoom the map at for example 7.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/):

> **Maps on Google Maps have an integer "zoom level"** which defines the
>   resolution of the current view. Zoom levels between 0 (the lowest zoom
>   level, in which the entire world can be seen on one map) to 21+ (down
>   to individual buildings) are possible within the default roadmap maps
>   view.